# Using .htaccess mod_rewrite to pass all URLs in a given directory to a single redirect script

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to use mod_rewrite to redirect any call to /real-estate/* to rewrite.php...i know i can redirect everything to rewrite.php with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rewrite.php?url=$1 [L]
```

I would like to have my urls formatted like /real-estate/12345/123-anywhere-st ....where the 123-anywhere-st would be ignored, and have `/real-estate/12345` sent to rewrite.php...id like the rewrite rule to only be used on /real-estate...all other areas of the site should function as is...Ive searched all over for a good tutorial or cheat sheet, but none that I can find actually explain how to format the mod_rewrite rules, they just give one or two examples and thats it...can anyone help, as well as maybe provide a link to somewhere I can learn

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteRule ^/real-estate/(.*)$ rewrite.php?url=$1 [L]

Comment: I was hoping for some sort of link to a tutorial or how-to but this does work...thanks

Comment: oh sorry, do you understand it or do you need me to explain it?